# Sorting of XML file by XMLElement's InnerText

Tags: c#, xml, sorting

Please have a look at the XML file. I would like to sort the XML file by `<Order>` tag

```
<MyRootNode>
  <Tab>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Order>200</Order>
  </Tab>
  <Tab>
    <Name>MNO</Name>
    <Order>100</Order>
  </Tab>
  <Tab>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <Order>90</Order>
  </Tab>
  <Tab>
    <Name>QWE</Name>
    <Order>40</Order>
  </Tab>
  <Tab>
    <Name>KML</Name>
    <Order>20</Order>
  </Tab>
</MyRootNode>
```

So the answer will be the following.

```
<MyRootNode>
  <Tab>
    <Name>KML</Name>
    <Order>20</Order>
  </Tab>
  <Tab>
    <Name>QWE</Name>
    <Order>40</Order>
  </Tab>
  <Tab>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <Order>90</Order>
  </Tab>
  <Tab>
    <Name>MNO</Name>
    <Order>100</Order>
  </Tab>
  <Tab>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Order>200</Order>
  </Tab>
</MyRootNode>
```

**How can I do it in C# 3.5 ?**

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Haris Hasan  Ohh... I am new to XML . But I am trying :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried,

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(xmlfile);
var orderedtabs = root.Elements("Tab")
                      .OrderBy(xtab => (int)xtab.Element("Order"))
                      .ToArray();
root.RemoveAll();
foreach(XElement tab in orderedtabs)
    root.Add(tab);
root.Save(xmlfile);
```

Answer (score 1):

use XSLT

E.g:

**dataSort.xslt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="MyRootNode">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="MyRootNode" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MyRootNode">
    <xsl:for-each select="Tab">
        <xsl:sort select="Order/text()" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Sample.cs:**

```
//convert data.xml to sortedData.xml

using System;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

class Sample {
    static public void Main(){
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load("dataSort.xslt");
        xslt.Transform("data.xml", "sortedData.xml");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to parse the XML file into a set of records, sort the records on the appropriate field, then write the result back out as a new XML file.

Comment: You could use DataTable.ReadXml() and DataTable.WriteXml() methods.

Answer (score 0):

if you use 
using System.Xml.Linq;

then you can get the sorted xlements like this

```
var xnodes = oldXDoc.Element("MyRootNode").Elements();
var sortedXNodes = xnodes.OrderBy(node => Convert.ToInt32( node.Element("Order").Value));
var newXdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("MyRootNode", sortedXNodes));
```