# Sort XmlElement by Attribute value

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0

I have

```
XmlElement root;
```

that contains structure like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<EntityCollection xmlns="">
    <Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <id>C</id>
        <CDate>2010-06-29T00:00:00</CDate>
        <Applicants>
            <PersonID>1</PersonID>     
            <Age>4651</Age>
            <IncomeCollection>
                <Amount>20</Amount>
                <Frequency>W</Frequency>
            </IncomeCollection>
        </Applicants>
        <Applicants>
            <PersonID>15</PersonID>     
            <Age>4651</Age>
            <IncomeCollection>
                <Amount>20</Amount>
                <Frequency>W</Frequency>
            </IncomeCollection>
        </Applicants>
        <Applicants>
            <PersonID>6</PersonID>     
            <Age>4651</Age>
            <IncomeCollection>
                <Amount>20</Amount>
                <Frequency>W</Frequency>
            </IncomeCollection>
        </Applicants>
        <tag>N</tag>
    </Application>
</EntityCollection>
```

**i want to sort the applicants by PersonID so that the result be like below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<EntityCollection xmlns="">
    <Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <id>C</id>
        <CDate>2010-06-29T00:00:00</CDate>
        <Applicants>
            <PersonID>1</PersonID>     
            <Age>4651</Age>
            <IncomeCollection>
                <Amount>20</Amount>
                <Frequency>W</Frequency>
            </IncomeCollection>
        </Applicants>
        <Applicants>
            <PersonID>6</PersonID>     
            <Age>4651</Age>
            <IncomeCollection>
                <Amount>20</Amount>
                <Frequency>W</Frequency>
            </IncomeCollection>
        </Applicants>
        <Applicants>
            <PersonID>15</PersonID>     
            <Age>4651</Age>
            <IncomeCollection>
                <Amount>20</Amount>
                <Frequency>W</Frequency>
            </IncomeCollection>
        </Applicants>
        <tag>N</tag>
    </Application>
</EntityCollection>
```

Comment: you want to sort the XML? why is that? ( *cough cough* the reading software should do that ), edit: also http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494275/sorting-of-xml-file-by-xmlelements-innertext

Comment: Indeed, @Najzero is correct.  The literal order in XML is irrelevant.  It should be the responsibility of the reader to consider such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altought XmlParsers don't guarantee that you will get the elements in the order in xml file, here is a solution using Linq2Xml

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(fname);
var applicants = xDoc.Descendants("Applicants")
                     .OrderBy(a=>(int)a.Element("PersonID"))
                     .ToList();
applicants.ForEach(a=>a.Remove());
xDoc.Root.Element("Application").Add(applicants);
xDoc.Save(fname);
```

Comment: what is fname? i have xmlement

Comment: @JustinHomes `fname` is the path to a xml file. If you have xml as `string` use `XDocument.Parse`

Comment: 'Altought XmlParsers don't guarantee that you will get the elements in the order in xml file': the order of elements inside XML IS relevant, XML parsers should (and do) guarantee that the order is kept reading and writing

Comment: @JustinHomes `using System.Linq;`