# How to save C# xml to an existing file

Tags: c#, xml, save

I have the following `xml code` (Highscores.xml):

```
<highscore>
  <score>
    <name>Pipo</name>
    <points>200</points>
  </score>
</highscore>
```

I have a textbox where the player need to write his name to save it. Also the points need to be saved.
How can I add these two items to my `xml` file?

Comment: Try the above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367730/how-to-change-xml-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"D:\Highscores.xml");
    var name = doc.SelectSingleNode("/highscore/score/name");
    if (name != null)
        name.InnerXml = "ojlovecd";
    var points = doc.SelectSingleNode("/highscore/score/points");
    if (points != null)
        points.InnerXml = "12345";
    doc.Save(@"D:\Highscores.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a LINQ version for completeness:

```
   XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\OldFile.xml");
   var score = xDoc.Element("highscore").Element("score");

   score.Element("name").Value = "NewName";
   score.Element("points").Value = "100";

   xDoc.Save(@"C:\NewFile.xml");
```

As always, null-check your variables before trying to do anything with them.

Comment: Thank you!! But I have another question: How can I sort the Points? So the highest points are on top?

Comment: @user2508085 See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9744678/353147