# C# ASP.NET Sort XML Nodes by custom attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, sorting

Is there a way we can sort xmlnodes based on attribute values? The point is that every child node has a different name, despite it, I want to sort them by attribute.
E.g.

```
<Doc>
<mar_03 data="03">
  <Mattina_Turno_1 />
</mar_03>
<dom_01 data="01">
  <Mattina_Turno_1 />
</dom_01>
<mer_04 data="04">
  <Mattina_Turno_1 />
  <Mattina_Turno_2 />
</mer_04>
</Doc>
```

Should become

```
<Doc>
<dom_01 data="01">
  <Mattina_Turno_1 />
</dom_01>
<mar_03 data="03">
  <Mattina_Turno_1 />
</mar_03>
<mer_04 data="04">
  <Mattina_Turno_1 />
  <Mattina_Turno_2 />
</mer_04> </Doc>
```

How can I do it? After sorting obviously I want to overwrite the file.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539948/how-to-sort-xml-files-by-a-node-attribute-in-c-sharp) answer does not fix my problem since i can not define the node "item" since every my nodes are named differently.

Thanks, and please do not mark it as duplicate, because it is not!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort XML files by a node attribute in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539948/how-to-sort-xml-files-by-a-node-attribute-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The following solution can not be applied here. @FerasAlSous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sorting**

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("FileName.xml");

    var res = xDoc.Element("Doc")
                    .Elements()
                    .OrderByDescending(c => (int) c.Attribute("data"));
```

Then to save it:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Doc", res));
doc.Save("FileName.xml");
```

Comment: OP has *one* file in which the nodes should be sorted.

Comment: Should not we define that the attribute "data" are in the doc child nodes?

Comment: I edit the answer , but you should define the attribute `data` to sort the element determined on value inside attribute `data`

Answer (score 1):

Please try,

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("File.xml");

        var result = xdoc.Element("Doc")
        .Elements()
        .OrderBy(s => (int)s.Attribute("data"));

        string xmlOutPut = string.Empty;

        result.ToList().ForEach(a =>
        {
            xmlOutPut += a;
        });
```

Where data and Doc is the parent element is your attribute according to your example. File.xml is your xml file name. You will get the sorted output in 'xmlOutPut'

or everything in a single Linq query,

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile2.xml");
        string xmlOutPut = string.Empty;

        xdoc.Element("Doc")
          .Elements()
          .OrderBy(s => (int)s.Attribute("data"))
         .ToList().ForEach(a =>
         {
             xmlOutPut += a;
         });
```

Comment: what about the two "element"? Should not they be the nodes name?